# How to move Git repo to Atlassian Stash over HTTPS

Tags: linux, git

My firm has been using Git for over a year now but we been using SSH and Gitolite.  We are moving to Atassin Stash over HTTPS.  Can someone please tell me the steps I have to take on moving a repo and also how to use it over https

I think I need to clone it using ssh but then how to a move it with using https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to migrate your existing repo to the new server, it's probably best to do a fresh clone, and then push the entire clone to the new server:

```
 git clone ssh://my.old.server/git/foo.git
 cd foo
 git remote set-url origin https://bla.blo.bli/git/foo.git
 git push --all
```

once the new server has been synched, the clients can be switched simply by changing the URL of your primary remote:

```
git remote set-url origin https://bla.blo.bli/git/foo.git
```

and continue to work.
that's all :-)